# Show custom key-bindings in the list of commands

Tags: key-bindings, helm

I'm using merlin in Emacs, and in my init.el file I have the following :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'merlin-type-expr)
```

But when I press `M-x` and type `merlin` to show the list of commands (via helm), some have shortcuts assigned to them, but not `merlin-type-expr`, even if the shortcut works.
You can see that here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CErmn.jpg

What should I do in order to see it? (if it is possible).

I'm using emacs 26.3 with helm and merlin.

Comment: It might help if you stated which library is causing those completion options to appear in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I used "helm" in tags but forgot to mention it in my post, my bad.

Comment: Please use the image button to show images I line and not the url link